# Unable to see records in lookup

Tags: apex, visualforce

While i am doing a lookup search, unless i have visited the object and it's in my recently view list i can't seem to find any of the records that were created by another system admin. We are both Sys Admins and i can't see any of the records posted by him in lookup.

Only after i click them they'll be in recently viewed however still unable to see them in search.

I have looked at permissions seeing if that would be a thing to prevent it, but so far no luck.

Comment: Are they very recently created records?

Answer (score 1):

Are you remembering your wildcards in your search criteria.

If you are using the pop-up lookup selector, don't forget you can't just search on any field, you are searching on the record name.

[image: lookup dialogue]

Comment: Yeah i put * on it but i get no records it's weird I have no idea what is happening

Comment: If enabled, [enhanced lookups](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=search_lookupdialog.htm&language=en_US) allow searching on other fields.

Answer (score 1):

Lookup dialogs show recently viewed records by default, and for all other require a search term to be provided.

The first response to this is usually just entering * as the search term, but that *does not work*. Salesforce requires at least two non-wildcard characters as part of the term.

*im* is a valid search term, while *, i*, *m are not.